# Request to Raspberry Pi not working when on wifi

Tags: flask, raspberry-pi, portforwarding

I'm relatively new to networking, so I suspect I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out what.

I have a rasberrypi on my local network. I've got a super minimal hello world flask nginx website set up, and I've enabled port-forwarding on my router for port 80/22 to go to the pi.

Now, the issue: I can access my site by entering the IP on different wifi networks. However when I try to do this same thing on my local network (ie on the wifi that my router is producing) it gives me a time out. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Comment: Ports are whole numbers in the range 0..65535. Your `80/22` doesn't look correct as a port.

Comment: sorry -- to be clear, I have port 80 AND port 22 forwarded (for http and ssh respectively). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: `I can access my site by entering the IP` ... which IP?  Be aware that if you're using the WAN IP of the router to succesfully get at this from outside, you need to use the Pi's local IP when you're connected to the router's wifi (internally).  Also be aware some routers may have  'client isolation' so different wifi devices can't tak to each other (eg. Useful for a cafe network).  I think you need to build a better picture of how this is setup.  An `nginx.conf` wouldn't hurt either.